# Get the length of the Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

```
export class AppComponent { 

  posts: any[];
  requestStream: any;

    constructor(http: Http){  
       http.get('https://api.github.com/users')
         .subscribe(  
         response => { this.posts = response.json(); });  
    }  
}
```

And:

```
<div *ngFor="let post of posts">
{{ post.login }}
</div>
{{ posts.length }}
```

The view shows everything well - login of every post and the length of posts (which is 30), but console gives error:

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

And other concern is that that url (https://api.github.com/users) actually consists of more records than 30 (46). So why I get only 30 records?

Comment: Add safe-nav operator to your interpolations: `{{ posts?.length }}`. And how do you know you got 46 posts? Have you checked the network tab?

Comment: Ah... Right, forgot the Elvis operator... But please check my pther concern - why I get only 30 records, while there are 46...?

Comment: How do you know you got 46 records?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I am very sorry

Comment: I just checked the first that has id 1, and the latest that has id46...

Comment: terrible, I know. Very sorry...

Comment: It's ok :-) but please don't encourage people to answer the questions that are duplicates.

Comment: Yes, Thanks I will. Just those damn ids made me duplicate this question... Hope this will not happen again...

Comment: Happens to the best of us :-)

Comment: Yeah, and I am far away the best :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error happened before the `http` gets the data, your posts value was undefined. To solve this you need to initialize the posts when you declare it.

```
posts = [];
```

or in your template you can use

```
{{ posts?.length }}
```